Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer orr writable account
    use anchor_lang::{
    prelude::*,
    system_program::{create_account, CreateAccount},
    };
    use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken, token_interface::{Mint, TokenAccount, 
    TokenInterface}
    };
    use spl_tlv_account_resolution::state::ExtraAccountMetaList;
    use spl_transfer_hook_interface::instruction::{ExecuteInstruction, 
    TransferHookInstruction};
    use anchor_spl::token_2022::burn;
    use anchor_spl::token_2022;
    use spl_tlv_account_resolution::account::ExtraAccountMeta;
    use spl_tlv_account_resolution::seeds::Seed;

    declare_id!("AXisjazgSH9etw9bwuyCCrwtTU4556puPB4B8oah3Est");

    #[program]
    pub mod transfer_hook {

    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_extra_account_meta_list(
        ctx: Context<InitializeExtraAccountMetaList>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // The `addExtraAccountsToInstruction` JS helper function resolving incorrectly
        let account_metas = vec![
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_pubkey(&token_2022::ID, false, false)?,
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_seeds(
                &[Seed::Literal {
                    bytes: "burn".as_bytes().to_vec(),
                }, Seed::AccountKey { index: 1 }],
                false, // is_signer
                false,  // is_writable
            )?,
        ];

        // calculate account size
        let account_size = ExtraAccountMetaList::size_of(account_metas.len())? as u64;
        // calculate minimum required lamports
        let lamports = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(account_size as usize);

        let mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[
            b"extra-account-metas",
            &mint.as_ref(),
            &[ctx.bumps.extra_account_meta_list],
        ]];

        // create ExtraAccountMetaList account
        create_account(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateAccount {
                    from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.to_account_info(),
                },
            ).with_signer(signer_seeds),
            lamports,
            account_size,
            ctx.program_id,
        )?;

        // initialize ExtraAccountMetaList account with extra accounts
        ExtraAccountMetaList::init::<ExecuteInstruction>(
            &mut ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.try_borrow_mut_data()?,
            &account_metas,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn transfer_hook(ctx: Context<TransferHook>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Hello Transfer Hook Before!");
        msg!("token program: {}", ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info().key());
        msg!("burn auth: {}", ctx.accounts.burn_authority.to_account_info().key());
        
        let mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[
            b"burn",
            &mint.as_ref(),
            &[ctx.bumps.burn_authority],
        ]];

        let _ = burn(CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            token_2022::Burn {
                authority: ctx.accounts.burn_authority.to_account_info(),
                from: ctx.accounts.destination_token.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
           },
           signer_seeds,
            ), amount / 2).unwrap();

        msg!("Hello Transfer Hook!");
        msg!("Amount: {}", amount);

        Ok(())
    }

    // fallback instruction handler as workaround to anchor instruction discriminator check
    pub fn fallback<'info>(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>],
        data: &[u8],
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let instruction = TransferHookInstruction::unpack(data)?;

        // match instruction discriminator to transfer hook interface execute instruction
        // token2022 program CPIs this instruction on token transfer
        match instruction {
            TransferHookInstruction::Execute { amount } => {
                let amount_bytes = amount.to_le_bytes();

                // invoke custom transfer hook instruction on our program
                __private::__global::transfer_hook(program_id, accounts, &amount_bytes)
            }
            _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData.into()),
        }
    }
    }

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct InitializeExtraAccountMetaList<'info> {

    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account, must use these seeds
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    }

    // Order of accounts matters for this struct.
    // The first 4 accounts are the accounts required for token transfer (source, mint, 
       destination, owner)
    // Remaining accounts are the extra accounts required from the ExtraAccountMetaList 
       account
    // These accounts are provided via CPI to this program from the token2022 program

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct TransferHook<'info> {

    #[account(
        token::mint = mint, 
        token::authority = owner,
    )]
    pub source_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        token::mint = mint,
    )]
    pub destination_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK: source token account owner, can be SystemAccount or PDA owned by another 
     program
    pub owner: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,

    /// CHECK: burn authority Account,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"burn", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub burn_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    }


can you share the full error logs

Token-2022ProgramInstruction

Program logged: "Instruction: TransferChecked"
Program invoked: UnknownProgram(9L8PsMa9UU8bGAHP7ueqNn3649bozWyiRy37b2VZwhay)
Program logged: "Instruction: TransferHook"
Program logged: "Hello Transfer Hook Before!"
Program logged: "token program:TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb"
Program logged: "burn auth:87JhJkhC4QQWTZuysuqJynhdiAYptvUoFTn9H5ycgiNH"
8eM9rJtgtNWnubXM8LYEAAPBoa24GH5ES17DM9BJXbPp's writable privilege escalated
Program returned error: "Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account"


Your program is being called from token-2022, and then your program is trying to CPI back into token-2022, which isn't possible. Re-entrancy is not allowed on Solana.
You'll need to update your solution to avoid burning in your transfer hook, or you can burn a token that belongs to SPL Token instead of SPL Token-2022.
